# Inspiron not waking up after lid open (Trusty)

Tags: 14.04, power-management, inspiron, lid, resume

I've installed Trusty (14.04.3 LTS) on a brand-new Dell Inspiron 13 (7000 series). Everything else seems to be working well, except that the laptop does not wake up after Suspend on opening the lid (it does start if the power button is pressed).

Having the laptop wake up on open is a convenience that I had on my previous Dell (XPS 13) also running Trusty. Is there some way this can be enabled?

TIA

s1b

Comment: This is something that does require hardware support but it's often included. So, before we get too far... Umm... Have you tried this with a different OS or did your laptop come with Ubuntu? I've come across a few, albeit not too many, laptops that do not resume when the lid opens.

Comment: Now that I think of it. Run `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` from the terminal and edit your post with the output.

Comment: `Device    S-state      Status   Sysfs node
EHC1      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
XHC      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the "when lid is closed" to Do Nothing and change it back to sleep again?

It is found in settings/Power

Comment: Thanks. I did it, but it does not appear to change anything.

Comment: because I can't comment yet. I'm gonna comment here. The output from the cat /proc/acpi/wakeup is unformatted in the comments which makes it hard to read. Can you put it in your main post instead?